# Two polynomials that differ by polynomial expansion of $e$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Let $h(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}$. Does there exist real polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $f(n)=h(n)g(n)$ for every positive integer $n$?

So far, I got that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ needs to be of the same degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\dfrac{1}{e-f(n)/g(n)}$. It is a rational function (i.e., a ratio of two polynomials), but what about its growth rate? Since $e-{f(n)\over g(n)}=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty{1\over k!}={1\over(k+1)!}+{1\over(k+2)!}+\dots<{1\over k\cdot k!}$, our function must grow about as fast as factorial, which is faster than any exponent, which is way faster then any rational function can do.

Comment: I think that should be $e-1$ instead of $e$. Also, can you explain your final inequality?

Comment: Yes, sure, $e-1$. As for the final one, see, $(k+2)!\ge (k+1)!(k+1),\,(k+3)!\ge (k+1)!(k+1)^2$, etc, hence the whole sum is bounded from above with the geometric series $1\over(k+1)^i$ multiplied by $1\over(k+1)!$.